# Merge 2 XML files, merge keys and apply it as a template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to files XML files: **language.xml** and **menu.xml**. The first one is loaded by default, the second is loaded with `<xsl:param />`.

language.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<language>
    <header>
        <menu>
            <title>Title of example</title>
        </menu>
        <menu>
            <title>Title of example 2</title>
        </menu>
        <menu>
            <title>Title of example 3</title>
        </menu>
    </header>
</language>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<header>
    <menu>
        <a>/example</a>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <a>/example2</a>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <a>/example3</a>
    </menu>
</header>
```

I need to match every /language/header/menu with every /header/menu. The positions are correct, so the first /language/header/menu corresponds with /header/menu.

So the desired output will be:

```
<a href="/example">Title of example</a>
<a href="/example2">Title of example 2</a>
<a href="/example3">Title of example 3</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks as if you posted the same input document twice. Where is the text "Example 2" supposed to come from? It's not in the input you posted. And where do you define the mapping between URL and link text? Seems some sort of index/key is missing, too.

Comment: @0xA3 Sorry! Typo error, I was hand-writing the output. Basically, language.xml has the anchor title and menu.xml has the href of the anchor. Thanks!

Comment: And how is the mapping defined? Is it simple by the position, i.e. the first menu/a is mapped to the first menu/title, the second to the second, etc?

Comment: Yes! That's it! Do you think that will be better if there is a id on every menu? <menu id="1">, 2, 3... For me it's not needed, but it is easier, is not a problem! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using match templates you can do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="localization" select="document('index.en.xml')" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="menu">
    <a href="{a}">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$localization/language/header/menu[$pos]/title"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @0xA3: This is answer is rigth, but I think it has a typo: `apply-imports` should be `apply-templates`...

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for the hint. It probably happened due to auto-completion and I didn't notice it because it works too (but makes no sense).

Comment: @0xA3: Also, +1 for an answer ussing pattern matching.

Comment: It's possible to have a variable in document()? I've tried but seems not to work. Like: `<xsl:variable name="locale" select="language/language" />` and then `<xsl:variable name="localitzation" select="document('index.$locale.xml')" />` . Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Isern Palaus: It is possible, but it requires you to use the `concat()` function to concatenate the strings explicitly (that's different from languages like PHP or Perl): `<xsl:variable name="localitzation" select="document(concat('index.', $locale, '.xml')" />`

Comment: @Isern Palaus: Also may need (with some processors) the use of p/2 `fn:document` for base URI like `document(concat('index.', $locale, '.xml'),/)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are saying the files should be linked based on their position as XML child nodes. In which case you want something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="menu">
  <a href="{.}">
    <xsl:variable name="position"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$param//menu[position() = $position]">
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```